# Best way to automate variable creation in R using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1:10), c(15, 70, 29, 64, 57, 29, 10, 80,81, 71)))

   V1 V2
1   1 15
2   2 70
3   3 29
4   4 64
5   5 57
6   6 29
7   7 10
8   8 80
9   9 81
10 10 71

cuts <- c(5, 10, 90, 95)
```

I would like to create logical variables for all (in this case, four) cut values `x` (e.g. `P5`, `P10`, `P90` and `P95`) that indicate whether `v2 <= x`. The straightforward way of adding variables "by hand" does not scale beyond a handful:

```
df %<>% 
    mutate( P5 = V2 <=  5) %>% 
    mutate(P10 = V2 <= 10) %>% 
    mutate(P90 = V2 <= 90) %>% 
    mutate(P95 = V2 <= 95)

   V1 V2    P5   P10  P90  P95
1   1 15 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
2   2 70 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
3   3 29 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
4   4 64 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
5   5 57 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
6   6 29 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
7   7 10 FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE
8   8 80 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
9   9 81 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
10 10 71 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

Obviously, to keep the data in "tidy" format, a final `gather(year, islegal, c(3;6))` should be applied.

An alternative that I tried is to do

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(cuts, function(x) { 
                df %>% mutate(year = x, islegal = V2 <= x) 
        })) %>% spread(year, islegal)

   V1 V2     5    10   90   95
1   1 15 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
2   2 70 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
3   3 29 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
4   4 64 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
5   5 57 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
6   6 29 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
7   7 10 FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE
8   8 80 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
9   9 81 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
10 10 71 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

Obviously, I would drop the final `spread()` to keep the data in "tidy" format.

**Question**: are there better or more generic ways of using `{dplyr}` than the second approach for automating variable creation (quantile-like cutoffs like here, or dummies or similar), that do not require explicitly typing out the contents of `cuts` like the first approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surely you don't need dplyr for something this simple.

```
names(cuts) <- paste0("p", cuts)
data.frame(df, lapply(cuts, function(x) df$V2 <= x))

   V1 V2    p5   p10  p90  p95
1   1 15 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
2   2 70 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
3   3 29 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
4   4 64 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
5   5 57 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
6   6 29 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
7   7 10 FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE
8   8 80 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
9   9 81 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
10 10 71 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: thanks, this is very nice. For some reason it never occurred to me to just bind the new data column-wise

Comment: I accepted this answer until @hadley comes along with a new verb to automate such tasks :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to "programatically" work with `dplyr`, you should look at the "standard evaluation" alternatives to the usual versions of the function. See the non-standard evaluation vignette (`vignette("nse", "dplyr")`).

Basically in addition to the  `mutate` function, there is a `mutate_` function with allows you to specify a list of transformations.  In your case, you can build your list with something like this

```
cuts <- c(5,10,90,95)
mymutate <- setNames(lapply(cuts , function(x) 
     lazyeval::interp(~V2<=x, x=x)), paste0("P", cuts ))
```

Then you can perform the transformation with

```
df %>% mutate_(.dots=mymutate )

#    V1 V2    P5   P10  P90  P95
# 1   1 15 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
# 2   2 70 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
# 3   3 29 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
# 4   4 64 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
# 5   5 57 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
# 6   6 29 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
# 7   7 10 FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE
# 8   8 80 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
# 9   9 81 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
# 10 10 71 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: thanks, this is helpful (btw I incorporated your naming `cuts` over my original `splits`, but now you changed your anwer, lol)

Comment: the one thing I worry about here, is that this is quite a bit more advanced than I would be comfortable with in teams of applied analysts. The stacking approach using `do.call()` and `rbind` is easier to explain, I suspect.

Comment: If you want "easier", then I would avoid dplyr in cases like this. (I only used dplyr because your question requested it)

Comment: in our team, we are trying to adopt `{dplyr}` consistently for most data manipulation tasks. our current experience is that the standard verbs work beautifully, but doing extra stuff requires quite a bit of effort. we haven't settled yet on the best mix of advanced stuff like lazy eval, regular dplyr and the plain old data frame manipulations

Comment: for maintainability, I would not use this, but it's good to know it's possible. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to eventually convert your data to a tidy data, you may simply start with one:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1:10), c(15, 70, 29, 64, 57, 29, 10, 80,81, 71)))
cuts <- data_frame(P=c(5, 10, 90, 95))

p_df <- df %>% tidyr::crossing(cuts) %>%
  mutate(flag=V2<=P)
p_df

#   V1 V2  P  flag
#1   1 15  5 FALSE
#2   1 15 10 FALSE
#3   1 15 90  TRUE
#4   1 15 95  TRUE
#5   2 70  5 FALSE
#...
```

If the original format is really what you want, `tidyr::spread` the result

```
p_df %>% 
  tidyr::spread(P, flag, sep="")
#   V1 V2    P5   P10  P90  P95
#1   1 15 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
#2   2 70 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
#3   3 29 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
#4   4 64 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
#5   5 57 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
#6   6 29 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
#7   7 10 FALSE  TRUE TRUE TRUE
#8   8 80 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
#9   9 81 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
#10 10 71 FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```